# Python - if în while loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am studiing the Python Fundamentals and i have some trouble understanding this folowing example:

```
c = 1 

while c < 5:
    c = c + 1

    if c >= 4:

        print("string")

        print(c)

   else:

        continue
```

And the output is:

string

4

string

5

Could someone explain to me please, why i have this output?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Side note: The `else` branch is (1) useless and (2) indented incorrectly.

Comment: I understand that the output is correct, but i don't understand how the If statement work in the while loop for this example, as long as the numbers generated by the while loop are smaller then 5 and the If statement requires a number greater or equal to 4

Comment: @Gabriel The condition is (re-)checked at the beginning of the loop. The last increment from 4 to 5 happens **after** the last successful condition check (`4 < 5`). That’s why `5` also makes it into the output. When you modify the variable `c` inside the loop, nothing will (immediately) happen. There is no automatic `break` that would respond to each `c += 1` and terminate the loop when `c` reaches `5`. The loop will only exit after the next full iteration. (You would add `if c >= 5: break` or the like after the increment if the loop was supposed to exit *immediately*.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the third iteration when c is 3.

`c = c + 1` increments the value to 4, and goes into the if statement and prints out the values.

Now c is equal to 4. On the next iteration, `c < 5` (because its value is 4) and loops again. It gets incremented again and goes into the if statement again.

Therefore, it prints out 2 more values, hence why you see your output.